# override linq properties

Tags: vb.net, linq, properties, overriding, partial

I am using Linq to Sql that generated a data contract for a table. I have a date field in that table which is a non-nullable field. I need to override the auto generated property of the date field to return a specific value, something like

Get 
    if_dt<>date.minvalue 
       return _dt
     else
     return string.empty
End Get

Is it possible to override an autogenerated property in the designer.vb file using a partial class? I dont want to create a new property as it is currently being accessed in n number of places and I dont want to change it in every place.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to modify the .designer file or inherit from it and change the behavior of that property (but I guess the auto-generated property won't be virtual so you'll need to edit it anyway)

Comment: The problem with editing an auto-generated property is that the changes will get wiped away when the designer file is regenerated.

Comment: Yep. In that case, you can add a unit test that ensures it works as expected and at least you'll know if you forgot to update it. Anyway, I don't know if Linq-to-sql won't get mad if you change the behavior of the get... maybe it's using that accessor and having a different value than the one it stored may break things.